Error reading a .txt file with np.loadtxt python
I'm trying to read a .txt file but I got this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
this is my code.
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('Data.txt')
print(data)

how could I fix it?

probably your file was encoded in utf-16 format that's why you're seeing a Unicode error! can you try this out:
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('data.txt', encoding='utf-16')
print(data)

As you didn't mention file content, can you confirm if it's worked or what type of new error you're seeing?

Read the comment made by Mark Tolonen for better explanation about the error


incase if this didn't work then try this instead encoding='ISO-8859-1'

To further expand on the answer, U+FEFF is the BOM (byte order mark) code point used by UTF-16 to indicate big- or little-endian encoding of the UTF-16 code units.  FF FE indicates little-endian if they are the first two bytes, so seeing FF is a good guess that it is UTF-16-encoded.
